# Trying to use AJAX to grab parameter of function and pass to PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have an HTML input with a function and parmeter set to it like so

```
<input onclick='myFunc($count)' type='button' value='ClickMe'>;
```

I also have script references to JQuery and my script file

```
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Inside my myscript.js file I have the contents as such

```
function myFunc(x) {
 alert(x);

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "myphp.php",
            method: "post",
            data: { param1: "x" },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(strMessage) {

            }
      })
})
```

}

Here is my myphp.php file

```
<?php

    $param1 = $_GET['param1'];
    echo $param1;
?>
```

As you can see in the javascript file, I have alert(x); to test that the function is grabbing the $count variable and so far that is working (the correct value appears in the alert box). However, I want to pass that x parameter to the PHP script but my PHP script won't echo anything, I assume the line where I have param1 is wrong. Any tips?

Comment: remove the quotes from data: { param1: "x" }, in your javascript and add `alert(strMessage);` inside of the `success: function( strMessage ) { }` curly braces.

Comment: I followed your instructions and removed the alert(x); function underr myFunc() and when I click the button I get an alert but nothing inside the alert. This would mean that either the parameter is not being passed in AJAX and/or PHP? It is kind of hard to test if AJAX is calling the PHP file from within the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX call you are using a POST method, so in order to catch the variable in PHP you need to access it from $_POST:

```
<?php
   $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
   echo $param1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making the XHR with POST method

> `method: "post",`

and youre looking for it in the GET array

> `$_GET['param1']`;

Change either to post or get (keeping in mind your scenario) and you should be good imo.

read more here to know about the different methods of sending http requests: https://www.guru99.com/php-forms-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method in AJAX but trying to grab the value in `$_GET` which is wrong.

In your PHP code, just replace `$_GET['param1']` with `$_POST['param1']` and it works.

or If you like to use `$_GET` in your PHP code then change the method in AJAX or use `$.get`. Examples can be found on W3School.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp